# API is not fetching data in console when it is placed in javascript?

Tags: json, wordpress, api

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Vehicle Smart Sample</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="vehicle-smart-sample-form">
 <label for="reg">Enter your reg</label>
 <input type="text" id="reg"/>
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
 <div id="results">
 Results will appear here.
 </div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var myAppId = "<REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-API-KEY!>";
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#vehicle-smart-sample-form").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var reg = $("#reg").val();
 $.ajax({
 "async": true,
 "crossDomain": true,
 "url": "https://api.vehiclesmart.com/rest/vehicleData?reg=" + reg + "&isRefreshing=false&appid="+myAppId,
 "method": "GET",
 "headers": {
 "Content-Type": "application/text",
 "Accept": "application/json",
 "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
 }
 }).done(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
 if (response && response.Success) {
 $("#results").html(
 "<p>Make:" + response.VehicleDetails.Make + "</p>" +
 "<p>Model:" + response.VehicleDetails.Model + "</p>" +
 "<p>Taxed:" + response.VehicleDetails.Taxed + "</p>" +
 "<p>Motd:" + response.VehicleDetails.Motd + "</p>"
 );
 } else {
 $("#results").html(
 "<p>ERROR: "+response.ServiceMessage+"</p>"
 );
 }
 });
 });
 });
 </script>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that they have given me notice that NOTE - You should not put your API key in your HTML / JavaScript then where I put the API key to get the values which I need
and I want to implement it in Wordpress do I need still PHP code to get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to hide this key in your Javascript code, the only way to do it is to wrap your request with PHP or any other Back-End technology.

Comment: Thanks, dear for your suggestion my problem solved after hours of work in the back-end as you told me to do that

Comment: Great! Bravo to you!